# How to parse final domain from URL

Tags: python, url

I have a monster Facebook URL "https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fon.theatln.tc%2FEQs2HvJ%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR3TDwS8n30YYzCVqPceAVd3D_OYmy_SHWGTqKjNVPaI_C0qZn9OgIMRdAQ&h=AT2IGmpY8Hn4DC7nr9l8PScyiYSQYxxP9mY9cA0z09dgbhN0s4nv6lXhrxXDtRVkfwDbRqb5jMMiK_XIVkUooNdUlNA1v56my_FaYOPy7CskvfoqH5VrrICUs7qoq83L_TWzmm8SE4pp8v1l0ikDBvky35KSq3FCGTLhgkTm3XP4XNXCur-R80JJwwmWtLspm5tbpx26475YU1yUdognJg2CCCredWJehAth4xsqeOFUw40EvwWtBrtRgDZdE3ERHr7_53dccR6XnZqR5Jwqdh-UkVkY-UdItvLicSwmjWT7IErBGTmBDoFx0pQk4Hc4SvoJ-CIZkRwOBUHA41-OzQIvlSqbbWdCZvvs2b9b3PO87ZFlh07XKnj7Lp4EJD_SPl-10yDvEZOaLfz23Mljr2aVTcnuDw9mWqWtb_bY0LLiCKJlmUK6CU2fzfJre6aN1AfOncKnTLVa6Kf1-cB-F5ftF8icUWye1hBmJ5LQCxbqlq1AAyonYk2L-Kiw6nytcu5g-MYCYhy8pAuOVn_YioWY0wa93xjlySV45GkMW3H0xtv_tRVnPsGo-Ts0CpshD1Xx9B9txOXP-WvipQ9AXV2uBN33WXq01xULSRr3bN3qGKsR7wo3LOl8w0QwyMDH4-0"

I want to print the link that this URL directs to, which is
"https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2020/05/upload-black-mirror-hell-digital-heaven/611293/"

My code works to parse most Facebook URLs, but I've recently discovered it doesn't work on this type. It prints "http://on.theatln.tc/EQs2HvJ."

```
# url is the long FB url

            import urllib.parse as url_parse
            news_link = url_parse.unquote(url).split("?u=")[1].split("?fbclid")[0]
            print(news_link)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it works fine. That url (`http://on.theatln.tc/EQs2HvJ`) appears to be the link embedded in the facebook URL. If you fetch that link, it will probably resolve to a redirect to the final destination. Consider using the requests module to follow redirections:

```
>>> import requests
>>> x = requests.get('http://on.theatln.tc/EQs2HvJ')
>>> print(x.url)
https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2020/05/upload-black-mirror-hell-digital-heaven/611293/?utm_source=facebook&utm_campaign=the-atlantic&utm_content=edit-promo&utm_medium=social&utm_term=2020-05-07T16%3A56%3A03
>>>
```

Or alternatively:

```
>>> x = requests.head('http://on.theatln.tc/EQs2HvJ')
>>> print(x.headers['location'])
https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2020/05/upload-black-mirror-hell-digital-heaven/611293/?utm_source=facebook&utm_campaign=the-atlantic&utm_content=edit-promo&utm_medium=social&utm_term=2020-05-07T16%3A56%3A03
```

The advantage here is that it doesn't fetch the final url.

Comment: Hmmmm it worked on my local machine, but not when I deployed it to Heroku. I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Well, it sounds like the `requests` module is not installed. That's probably something you can rectify, but I'm not familiar with Heroku.

Comment: Turned out I didn't have it in the requirements.txt, all good now, thanks!